# SOA Style - Sharing data

Tags: soa

I'm considering an SOA architecture for a set of servives to support a business that Im consulting for, previously we used database integration where each application picked out what it need from a shared MS SQL database and worked with it etc.. We had various apps integrating with the monster database including java, .net and microsoft access, there was referential integrity as everything was tightly coupled.

I'm a bit confused about how to support data sharing between services.

Lets take Product Service which sits on top of a the Product database provided by the wholesaler each month. We build a domain model and sit this on to of the database with Hibernate or whatvever, implentation wise Product is a large object graph given the information provided by the wholesaler about the product.

Now lets say the Review service, Pricing Service, Shipping Service, and Stock Service will subscribe to ProductUpdated, ProductAdded, ProductDeleted. The problem is that each service only need part or some parts of the information about the Product. Shipping might only need the dimensions and weight. Pricing might only need product id, wholesale cost, volume discount, price effective to date. Review might need product id, product name, producer.

Is it standard practice just to publish the whole Product (suitable non-subscriber-specific contracts e.g. ProductUpdated, and a suitable schema - representing all product object graph) and let the subscribers map whatever they need to their domain models (or heck do what they want with, might not even have a domain model)...

Or as I write this I'm thinking maybe:

Product Service Publishes ProductAdded message (does not included product details just an ID of product and maybe a timestamp)

Pricing Service subscribes to ProductAdded and publishes RequestPricingForProduct message

Product Service Publishes ResultForPricingForProduct message

Hmm.. seems a little better... but it feels like I'm building the contract for Product Service based on what other services I can identify and what they are going to need, perhaps in future XYZ Service requires something different. Im going to stop there as I think it's getting clearer where I'm confused... perhaps the above will work because I should expose a way to return whatever that should be public hmmm right.

Any comments or direction greatly appreciated. Sorry if this appears half baked.

Answer (score 5):

I actually think the solution to this problem is to NOT share the data. SOA means that data is owned by a service - it is the technical authority of that data. I suggest reading a few Pat Helland articles, such as [Data On The Inside, Data On The Outside](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954587.aspx).

The only thing that should be shared between these different services is the primary key - the ProductId in your example. Otherwise, for each service, the data that needs to be transactionally consistent goes together.

There does not need to be one "Product". Each service can have a different view of the product in their service. For the Pricing service, you have a productId and a price. For the review service, a productId and a review. And so on.

Where this starts to confuse people is how to display this data in the UI if it's from all these disparate services. How can you show a list of reviews for a product that has the product name from the ProductService and the review text from the ReviewService?

The answer to that is to compose the UI from all the different services. Get the product from the product service and get the review data from the review service and then combine that data in the UI.

Answer (score 3):

I was in your position recently. The problem with directly exposing the underlying object through the service is that you increase coupling between layers, and there becomes little point in using a Service Oriented Achitecture at all. You would not be able to change these objects or business rules without affecting the web service too.

It sounds like you are on the right track. If you are serious about seperating your layers, then the most common pattern is to create a new separate set of message classes just for the web service, potentially each service, and translate your internal objects back and forth.

For an example of how to set up your service layer in this manner see the "Service Interface" pattern. On the client side of the service, there is an opposite pattern called "Service Gateway".

The Application Architecture Guide 2.0 has a whole chapter dedicated to the types of the decisions you are making ([http://apparchguide.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Chapter%2013%20-%20Service%20Layer%20Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998421.aspx)). I would download the whole guide.

Here is the portion most relevant to you. Long story short, if you take the time to create new coarse-grained methods, and message-based objects, you'll end up with a much better web service:

> Consider the following guidelines when designing a service interface: 
>   Consider using a coarse-grained interface to batch requests and minimize the number of calls over the network. 
>   Design service interfaces in such a way that changes to the business logic do not affect the interface. 
>   Do not implement business rules in a service interface. 
>   Consider using standard formats for parameters to provide maximum compatibility with different types of clients. 
>   Do not make assumptions in your interface design about the way that clients will use the service. 
>   Do not use object inheritance to implement versioning for the service interface.